# mini Rich Text editor

Tags: html, xml, richtext

ok, so i made a mini Rich text editor and if i want to insert a link i insert into the textarea the html like this: `<a href=http://google.com>go to google</a>`, it works just fine but when i reopen that text for editing i don't get the complete html tag...all i get is `go to google` without `<a href=http://google.com>` and `</a>`.
i have to mention that the text is stored in a `xml` document.
Can someone tell me where the problem is and how should i do it to get the full `<a href=http://google.com>go to google</a>` ? thanks

LATER EDIT:
in my xml file special characters are escaped(ex: `<` becomes `\&gt;`)

Answer (score 1):

When embedding HTML in XML, try escaping the special characters (less than, greater than, and ampersand) as

- &lt;
- &gt;
- &amp;

Comment: and how exactly should i do that? i tried something lilke: \&lt;a href=\"http://google.com\"\&gt;go to google\&lt;/a\&gt; but with no success

Comment: First, try removing the backslashes before the ampersands and the quotes. Backslashes are never used to escape things in XML. (And you don't need to escape the quotes.) I think the only things you can escape in XML are less than, greater than, and ampersand.

Having said that, I don't think removing backslashes will solve your original problem. If escaping with ampersands doesn't work, I'm fresh out of ideas. :-(